# нужно сделать 4 инпута введя в которых цифры и нажав на кнопку сортировать их по возрастанию используя только условные операторы if else

Tags: javascript

```js
function a5(){
    let a = +num1.value
    let b = +num2.value
    let c = +num3.value
    let d = +num4.value
    let max;
    let min;
    if(a>b){
        max = a;
        min = b;
    }
    else{
        max = b;
        min = a;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="num1">
<br><br>
<input id="num2">
<br><br>
<input id="num3">
<br><br>
<input id="num4">
<br><br>

<button onclick="a5()">A5</button>

<h1 id="result"></h1>

</body>
</html>
```

ни как не определюсь как писать алгоритм

Comment: То есть циклы нельзя?

Comment: Нет, только условные операторы, они там в нас хотят развить алгоритмичное мышление или что-то вроде этого

Answer (score 3):

Существует много алгоритмов сортировки. Ну например (сортировка выбором):

```js
console.log( my_sort() );

function my_sort() {
  let a = 115;
  let b = 7;
  let c = 12;
  let d = -5;
  
  if( b < a ) { // Второе меньше, чем первое?
    [a, b] = [b, a]; // Поменять их местами
  }
  if( c < a ) { // Третье меньше, чем первое? 
    [a, c] = [c, a]; // Тоже поменять местми
  }
  if( d < a ) {
    [a, d] = [d, a];
  }
  // Все числа сравнили с первым и поменяли местами при необходимости.
  // Теперь точно можно сказать, что в `a` хранится самое маленькое число ( -5 )
  
  // Про `a` забыли, теперь сравнить третье и четвертое со вторым.
  if( c < b ) {
    [b, c] = [c, b];
  }
  if( d < b ) {
    [b, d] = [d, b];
  }
  // Теперь точно `b` меньше, чем `c` и `d`

  
  if( d < c ) {
    [c, d] = [d, c];
  }
  
  return [a, b, c, d];
}
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLq7nB9bV0M&t=18m10s - классная лекция про сортировки. Там на питоне, но алгоритмы-то не отличаются) Можно подсмотреть и попробовать повторить и их на JS. Хотя в реальной жизни в будущем будете использовать встроенную `Array.sort()`

Answer (score 1):

Зачем вообще нужны `if-ы` ? :(

```js
var counter = 0
function out(d, e) {
  console.log((e ? 'end' : (counter++)) + '=> ' + JSON.stringify(d))
}

function sort([a, b, c, d]) {
  out([a, b, c, d]);

  (a > b && ([a, b] = [b, a]));
  (b > c && ([b, c] = [c, b]));
  (c > d && ([c, d] = [d, c]));
  out([a, b, c, d]);
  
  (a > b && ([a, b] = [b, a]));
  (b > c && ([b, c] = [c, b]));
  (c > d && ([c, d] = [d, c]));
  out([a, b, c, d]);
  
  (a > b && ([a, b] = [b, a]));
  (b > c && ([b, c] = [c, b]));
  (c > d && ([c, d] = [d, c]));

  return [a, b, c, d]
}

var inp = [42, 8, 21, -4]
out(sort(inp), true)
```

Comment: if-ы нужны для ясности и понятности кода. Чем больше "скрытых механик" JS вы используете, тем сильнее будут ругаться Ваши коллеги при чтении Вашего кода.

Краткость - это хорошо, но не в ущерб понятности

Comment: Но код крутой! Хоть я и не сразу вкурил. Так и быть, лайк!)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" value="6" class="qwe">
<input type="text" value="1" class="qwe">
<input type="text" value="4" class="qwe">
<input type="text" value="2" class="qwe">
<input type="button" value="Отсортировать" onclick="sort_inputs();">

<script>
    sort_inputs = () => {
        let arr = [];
        document.querySelectorAll('.qwe').forEach(el => {
            arr.push(el.value);
        });

        for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
                if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
                    let tmp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                    arr[i + 1] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(arr);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Mister X, спасибо за ответ, но нужно использовать только условные операторы if else

Comment: Надо обратить внимание, что `sort` по умолчанию сортирует всё как строку. Поэтому 11 окажется меньше, чем 9 ) Ну а если читерить, можно так - `console.log( [...document.querySelectorAll('.qwe')].map( e => e.value ).sort( (a,b) => a - b ) );`

Comment: OPTIMUS PRIME, спасибо за ответ, но нужно использовать только условные операторы if else

Comment: @Vahan дописал сортировку через if. Но ИМХО это плохая сортировка

Answer (score 0):

Что-то незаслуженно забыли рекурсию  ≧(◕ ‿‿ ◕)≦
Накидал "примерчик" чтоб можно было любое количество значений вводить через запятую в одном инпуте. Валидация входных данных упрощенная, а сортировка вполне себе полноценная.

```js
const buttonSubmit =  document.querySelector('.sort__submit');
const inputElement =  document.querySelector('.sort__input');
const displayResult = document.querySelector('.sort__result');

/**
 *  приведение значений массива к типу number. Выполнено упрощенно - пропускает числа из строк
 *  начинающихся с числа. Пример: "4рро" = 4
 *  @param array <array of string>  массив со всем занчениями из input.value
 *  @return <array of numver> только числовые значения
 */
const arrayToNumber = (array) => {
  return array.filter(item => parseInt(item)).map(item => parseInt(item))
}

/**
 *  поиск минимального значения в массиве и погружение его на позицию [0]
 *  выполняется рекурсивным перебором. Окончание рекурсии - в массиве единственный элимен
 *  @param array <array of number>    массив значений
 *  @return result <array of number>  массив с минимальныз значением на позиции [0]
 */
const findMinValue = (array) => {
  let result = []

  if (array.length > 1) {
    const shortArray = findMinValue(array.slice(1));
    
    if (array[0] > shortArray[0]) {
      result = result.concat(shortArray[0]).concat(array[0]).concat(shortArray.slice(1));
    } else {
      result = result.concat(array[0]).concat(shortArray);
    }
  } else {
      result.push(array[0]);
  }
  
  return result
}


/**
 *  сортировка массива выполняется последовательным поиском минимального значения и добавления
 *  его в результирующий массив. Массив для следующего поиска минимального значения сокращается на 
 *  один элемент. Рекурсия прекращается при условии что в массиве осталось единственное значение.
 *  @param array <array of number>  массив со значениями для сортировки
 *  @return result <array of number>  упорядоченный массив
 */
const sortEasy = (array) => {
  let result = [];
  
  if (array.length > 1) {
    const setMinArray = findMinValue(array);
    result = result.concat(setMinArray[0]).concat(sortEasy(setMinArray.slice(1)));
    } else {
      result.push(array[0]);
    }

  return result;
}


const sortStart = () => {
  const inputArray = inputElement.value.replace(/\s/g, '').split(',');
  const sortArray = sortEasy(arrayToNumber(inputArray));
  
  if (typeof(sortArray[0]) !== 'undefined') {
    displayResult.innerHTML = sortArray.join(', ');
    } else { 
      displayResult.innerHTML = 'o_O it\'s not a number...';
    }
  }

const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
  const keyDown = event.key;
  
  if (keyDown === 'Enter') {
    event.preventDefault()
    sortStart()
    }
  }

inputElement.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
buttonSubmit.addEventListener('click', sortStart)
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa:400,700&display=swap');

* {
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
}

.sort {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px 50px 50px;
  width: 400px;
  user-select: none;
}

.sort__title {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.sort__input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.sort__submit-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.sort__input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}

.sort__input-placholder {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 9px;
  left: 10px;
  color: darkblue;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.sort__display {
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 40%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #d0d0d0;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.sort__result {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 50%;
  animation: resultShow 7s infinite linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #606060;
}

.sort__submit {
  outline: none;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #606060;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

@keyframes resultShow{
  0% {
    transform: translate(40%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="sort">
  <h2 class="sort__title">Sort with "IF" and "ELSE" only</h2>
  <div class="sort__input-wrapper">
    <input class="sort__input" autofocus type="text" placeholder="give me your numbers here  (=^‥^=)">
    <span class="sort__input-placholder">Ммм... пиши сюда числа через запятую! Не тяни за хвост!</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sort__submit-wrapper">
    <div class="sort__display">
      <span class="sort__result">Waiting your results...</span>
    </div>
    <button class="sort__submit" type="button">Sort me please</button>
  </div>
</form>
```